# Pointers to Aviation Scholarships

Tags: commercial-aviation

I want to become a pilot, but as you know, I should take some training course on aviation. Currently I am searching for Aviation Scholarships because I can not sponsor myself. Can you give me some pointers please?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding funding to learn to fly.

Answer (score 1):

Scholarships dot com has a list of a few scholarship programs:  https://www.scholarships.com/financial-aid/college-scholarships/scholarships-by-type/aviation-scholarships/

However I am not sure if you are looking to get aviation training for a career, or for personal fulfilment.  There are also some schools that offer various aviation related programs (Embry-Riddle being the best known in the US).  Some of them may have separate scholarship programs that are not specifically listed on the Scholarships.com site.

There are also some places throughout the world that offer "learn to fly" programs.  I have a friend that works for a company that even offers their employees all the coursework and flying required for a private pilot license as a training subsidy (Kollsman, in New Hampshire).

Comment: Thank you. I look to get aviation training for a career.

Comment: What country are you located in?  The scholarships link I provided are mostly for the US.  If you are outside the US, I don't know if those would apply.

Comment: I am in Ethiopia, Africa.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://blog.internationalstudent.com/2012/10/aviation-scholarships/

Comment: And here is a school in your country.  They may be able to offer some advice on a scholarship: http://www.ethiopianairlines.com/en/schools/pilot/